# How can you handle nested `TabView`s with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I use 2+ `TabView`s with `PageTabViewStyle()` to render "pagers": a horizontal one and then a vertical one per horizontal pane?

Currently, I'm rendering the layout as such.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            // custom nested TabView 1
            VerticalTabView {}
            // custom nested TabView 2
            VerticalTabView {}
        }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}
```